# Snake game in Pygame, how to make apple stay in the same place

Tags: python, pygame

I'am a begginer working with pygame and python itself. I'am making snake game but I can't figure out how to make apple stay in the same place. So far I made a game board and starting snake. Apple is spawning but the problem is that it's changing it's place every second and I can't figure out how to stop it

Here's my code so far:

```
 import pygame
 import sys
 import random

 pygame.init()

 SPAWNSNAKE = pygame.USEREVENT          #events
 pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNSNAKE, 800)

 WHITE = (150, 150, 150)
 RED = (255, 0, 0)
 GREEN = (30, 50, 30) #colors
 BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

 FPS = 1
 WIDTH = 500
 HEIGHT = 500

 DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
 DISPLAY.fill(GREEN)

 grid_size = 25

 snake_list = []
 apple_list = []
 grid_list = []


class Snake: #creates a starting snake

   def __init__(self):
       self.snake = [(0, 475), (25, 475), (50, 475), (75, 475), (100, 475)]
       self.snake_width = grid_size
       self.snake_height = grid_size

   def create_snake(self):
       for x, y in self.snake:
       snake_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.snake_width, self.snake_height)
       snake_list.append(snake_rect)

   def draw_snake(self):
       for rectangle in snake_list:
       pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, BLACK, rectangle)


   def draw_grid(): #draws game board
       for x in range(0, WIDTH, grid_size):
           for y in range(0, HEIGHT, grid_size):
               rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, grid_size, grid_size)
               pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, WHITE, rect, 1)
               grid_list.append(rect)


class Apples:
    def create_apple(self): #creates an apple and adds it to the list
        apple = random.choice(grid_list)
        apple_list.append(apple)

    def draw_apple(self): #draws that apple on screen
        for apple_rectangle in apple_list:
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, RED, apple_rectangle)


snake = Snake()
apples = Apples()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    draw_grid()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             sys.exit()
         if event.type == SPAWNSNAKE:
             snake.create_snake()
         if len(apple_list) == 1: #always keeps apple count 1
             apple_list = apple_list[1:]
             DISPLAY.fill(GREEN)  #refreshes display so that previous apples dissapears(works so far but that 1 apple changes it's place every second)
             draw_grid()

print(apple_list)
apples.create_apple()
snake.draw_snake()
apples.draw_apple()
pygame.display.update()
```

What can I do so that apple is always at the same place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects). Don't create a class of apples. Create a class for an apple. You can create as many instances as you want from this one class:

```py
class Apple:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = random.choice(grid_list)
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, RED, self.rect)
```

Create the apples and add them to a list of apples before the application loop. Draw the apples in the list in the application loop:

```py
apple_list = []
apple1 = Apple()
apple_list.append(apple1)
apple2 = Apple()
apple_list.append(apple2)

# [...]

while True:
    # [...]

    for apple in apple_list:
        apple.draw()

    # [...]
```